# Javascript - AJAX Post Request JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to send the following HTTP Request using AJAX POST:

When I launch this code, the page crashes. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to do this? I just want to do the HTTP request in my web browser. What is the easier way to do this? I am generating the variables for the HTTP request using Javascript, that's why I want to do this in Javascript through the browser.

Comment: Use `error` instead of `failure` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/0gxb9Lo9/#&togetherjs=gbei89Uwkr)

Comment: Did not change anything. Page still crashes.

Comment: can you describe what you mean by "page crashes" - do you get errors in the **developer** tools console that could be of interest in debugging your code?

Comment: `var Host = example.com` - syntax error, unless you have an Object called `example` with a property called `com`

Comment: @Jaromanda X, the site first freezes and then after a while it just crashes and I have to reload it. And I have quotes around the Host variable.

Comment: You don't have to stringify the POST data, try: `var Req = {"Password":"Test","RegDate":"2015-01-12","User":"James22"};`

Comment: How long is your expected server response? As you have `console.log(data)` on success, it may crash your browser if the data is too long. And the url param should start with "http://" as well.

Comment: `it just crashes` - what does? a site doesn't crash, unless you mean the server is crashing!! - so, there's nothing in the **developer** tools console that shows what's going wrong? seems odd that there's a "crash" and no diagnostic information available anywhere - what browser are you using?

Comment: @Tuyen - `You don't have to stringify the POST data` - you actually do have to if you want to send JSON